Laravel + Redis + DDEV
my cache driver is set to Redis in my Laravel app, running locally with ddev and ddev-redis. When I use the Redis Facade set command, the data stored and I can see it via Redis CLI. However when I use the Cache Facade, with the put command, the data is stored somewhere (but where?)... but I don't see it with Redis CLI.
I would like to use the Cache Facade. And how can I know where the data is stored when using Cache::put ?
Thank you

Cache::put uses the default cache as configured in your config/cache.php file. By default this would use the filesystem.

The issue was that Laravel writes cache data into Redis DB 1, but redis-cli loads DB 0 by default.
